# How do I declare a static variable in a PHP class but define it in a class which extends the base class?

Tags: php, mysql, static, extend

I'm have a DatabaseObject Class that has select, insert, update and delete methods defined. The purpose of the class is to represent a subset of rows in my MySQL database as a PHP object. The constructor calls MySQL's SELECT command and the destructor calls the DELETE command (unless I ask it not to).

Here is my DatabaseObject class:

```
class DatabaseObject {  
    protected $table;
    protected $index_field;

    private $data;

    function __construct($id) {
        //MySQL SELECT and assign resource to data
    }

    function __destruct() {
        //MySQL UPDATE
    }

    public function insert($data) {
        global $db;     //Database Class for using MySQL

        $fields = array();
        $values = array();

        foreach ($data as $field => $value) {
            $fields[] = "`".$field."`";
            $values[] = "'".$db->escape($value)."'";
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$this->table." (".join(', ', $fields).") VALUES (".join(', ', $values).")";
        if($db->query($sql)) {
            return $db->insertID();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //More methods; update(), delete(), select()
}
```

I extend the DatabaseObject class when I want to access a specific table. For example, my User class is for my user table. Here it is:

```
class User extends Object {
    public static $anonymous_data = array('user_id' => 0, 'user_level' => ANONYMOUS, 'username' => 'Anonymous');

    function __construct($user_id = NULL) {
        global $db;
        $this->db = $db;

        $this->table = USER_TABLE;
        $this->index_field = 'user_id';

        parent::__construct($user_id);
    }

    function __destruct() {
        parent::__destruct();
    }

    //Other user methods; login(), logout() etc.
}
```

Now, I would like to be able to call the insert method from the user class without having already instantiated the User class. I'm pretty sure, I have to make it static to do so. How do I make the insert method static, but still allow it to use the table which was defined in the extension class?

In other words, I want to be able to do this:

```
User::insert($data);        //INSERT into user table
AnotherClass::insert($data);    //INSERT into another table
```

...without instantiating either class.

Comment: You can't, unless you define a separate static method with a different name like `insertStatically` or something.

Comment: Let me point out that you are entirely missing the point of *Object Oriented* Programming by using static class calls and `globals`. [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/)

Comment: I think you have an error in the code you've pasted, class User extends Object {, I think it should be: class User extends DatabaseObject {

Comment: Semi-off-topic: This `global $db;` inside a class === bad. Also, maybe you should use the `static` keyword to define a static function?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public static $anonymous_data = array();

    public static function aStaticMethod() {
        self::$anonymous_data = array(key, value);

        foreach (self::$anonymous_data as $key => $value) {
             echo "$key => $value";
        }
    }
}

Foo::aStaticMethod();
$classname = 'Foo';
$classname::aStaticMethod(); // As of PHP 5.3.0
?>
```

For a static method.  However be aware static variables CAN NOT be accessed this way.  Read more about this example and the static key word here: [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Updated: Using `self` instead of `$this->` example.

Comment: Also you mention static variable in your title and in your question you talk about a function/method/member what ever you'd like to call it.  For variables the object MUST exist.  Unless your wanting to just make a private/protected variable and make get/set methods.

Comment: Also noticed this, "How do I make the insert method static, but still allow it to use the table which was defined in the extension class?"  Well to define said table the object would also have to exist... Which would give you access to the method.

Comment: I don't think this solves my problem. My problem arises when I try to access $this->table_name in the static method. I get an error that says I can't user $this in a static method. So I tried making $table_name static, but then it won't allow me to override $table_name in the User class.

Comment: Use `self::$table_name` not `$this->table_name`.  You can not use `$this` pseudo code inside a static method. And leave the variable as `static`.